# Meteor/VueJS publish specific item

Tags: vue.js, meteor

I'm trying to publish the user associated with the current event
but I think I have not fully understood the principle of publication and subscription between meteor and vuejs

Server side :

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import Events from './collections';
import moment from "moment";

const currentWeek = moment().week();
const currentYear = moment().year();
const currentEvent = Events.findOne({ week: currentWeek, year: currentYear })

Meteor.publish('currentUser', function () {
  return Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: currentEvent.user_id } );
});
```

Client side :

```
export default {
  meteor: {
    $subscribe: {
      currentUser: [],
    },
    currentUser() {
      return Events.findOne()
    }
  }
}
```

the client returns the first user of the collection and not the one expected for the event given as a parameter of the publication.

Can you tell me where I am wrong I have a lot of trouble documenting me on good practices

Comment: Where do you get `currentWeek` and `currentYear` from?

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: Have you checked `currentEvent.user_id`?

Comment: @ghybs yes I get the ID of the current event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here:

First, a publication is intended to return a cursor (using `.find`) and not a single document(which is done using `.findOne`).

Second, the current code on the server only uses the moments of the startup / at the time the module is imported, because the code is on global scope and is not re-executed. So if your server runs longer than a week / year it won't return the accurate set of docs.

In order to return all documents that match the query use `.find`. In order to always get the current moments you may wrap this inside a function. Summarized the code could look like this:

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import Events from './collections';
import moment from "moment";

const getCurrentEvent = () => {
  const currentWeek = moment().week();
  const currentYear = moment().year();
  return Events.findOne({ week: currentWeek, year: currentYear });
}

Meteor.publish('currentUser', function () {
  const currentEvent = getCurrentEvent()
  return Meteor.users.find({ _id: currentEvent.user_id });
});
```

Further readings:

https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-publish

https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html

Comment: Thx for your answer, it was difficult for me to understand the principle of sub-scription and publication but I'm finally starting to see more clearly. Thx for links!